# Update List Item Version field value using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, versioning, list-item

I have list item contains multiple versions

[image]

I'm trying to change any particular version field value

e.g. : in picture I'm trying to change Title field value of version 5.0

Is it possible to change version field value using powerShell?

Answer (score 2):

We cant update previous versions of list item as there is no way/no method available using which we can persist those changes. This wouldn't be a supported function as whats the point of having version control and auditing if you can edit the information stored.

[update properties (metadata) of old versions of documents in Sharepoint](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f0f60554-79fb-47b6-b672-54295ce8d868/how-to-update-properties-metadata-of-old-versions-of-documents-in-sharepoint-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Comment: I'm in need of this now, as the version history changed when using SPListItem.MoveTo another (archive) document library. All versions "Modified by" got set to the user using the function, thus history lost. The information seems to be still there (on files), but not on Version objects.